# Carousel with asp.net web forms repeater

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, bootstrap-4, webforms

I am trying to make a carousel inside a repeater in asp.net web forms. It works, but the problem is that it show only one card in the row rather than 3 card in each row! I have tried to find a solution but nothings work right with me!

Could you help me here please.

This is the result:
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nWjCY.png)
and this is what it supposed to be like:
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NQDns.png)

Here is the code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>
    <title>Snippet - GoSNippets</title>
    <link href='https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/5.0.0-alpha1/css/bootstrap.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>
    <link href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css' rel='stylesheet'>
    <style></style>
    <script type='text/javascript' src=''></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/5.0.0-alpha1/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
</head>

<body oncontextmenu='return false' class='snippet-body'>
    <section class="pt-5 pb-5">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-6">
                    <h3 class="mb-3">Carousel cards title </h3>
                </div>
                <div class="col-6 text-right">
                    <a class="btn btn-primary mb-3 mr-1" href="#carouselExampleIndicators2" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                        <i class="fa fa-arrow-left"></i>
                    </a>
                    <a class="btn btn-primary mb-3 " href="#carouselExampleIndicators2" role="button" data-slide="next">
                        <i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-12">
                    <div id="carouselExampleIndicators2" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                        <div class="carousel-inner">
                            <div class="row">
                                <asp:Repeater ID="repeaterUpcomingShows" runat="server">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <div class="carousel-item <%# Container.ItemIndex == 0 ? "item active" : "item" %>">
                                            <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
                                                <div class="card">
                                                    <img class="img-fluid" src="assets/img/scenery/<%# Eval("showImageLink") %>">
                                                    <div class="card-body">
                                                        <h4 class="card-title"><%# Eval("showName") %></h4>
                                                        <p class="card-text"><%# Eval("showStartDate") %></p>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:Repeater>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <script type='text/javascript'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is code behind:

```
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        getGallaryDetails();
    }


    private void getGallaryDetails()
    {
        CRUD myCrud = new CRUD();
        string mySql = @"select * from shows  where showGalleryID=" + 1;

       // DataTable dt = myCrud.getDtPassSql(mySql);
        
        DataSet ds = myCrud.getDsPassSql(mySql);
        repeaterUpcomingShows.DataSource = ds;
        repeaterUpcomingShows.DataBind();


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like bootstrap's carousel has options for putting multiple carousel-items in one slide. The simplest solution for you may be to use something other than bootstrap - there are other javascript plugins that can do something more like what you're looking for; one I'm familiar with off the top of my head is Slick https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/.